# Unable to sync with origin/master

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I want to get the latest files at the remote origin/master using TortoiseGit. I did `fetch`, `pull`, etc. But it is not bringing in the version that exists on the remote. I even tried `git checkout origin/master -- <file>`

Before doing all this, I created a branch and pushed some changes on that branch to the remote. That branch was *NOT merged* at the remote. Everyone else in my team is able to get the correct versions that exist on the remote.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us a how your branches look like?

Comment: I created DG_child branch and pushed it to remote. Apparently the branch is not using the *latest* origin/master code. So it was not merged with the remote. Now I want to get the latest origin/master files, create another branch and push it to the remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# update to latest master
git fetch origin master

# create a new branch DG_child_new from DG_child and checkout it immediately
git checkout -b DG_child_new DG_child

# rebase your current branch DG_child_new on top of up-to-date master from origin
git rebase origin/master

# push DG_child_new to origin
git push -u origin DG_child_new
```

Comment: Hi Paul, my command line GIT is not configured to use the remote. It is only good for creating local branches and checking out. Is there anyway to do the same in Tortoise GIT? Thanks

Comment: @user2654788 I don't use TortoiseGIT, but I'm sure all mentioned commands are available there. Also, what do you mean by "not configured to use the remote"?

Comment: I ran rebase from Tortoise GIT and the message says "Current branch DG_child_new is up to date". The only options are "Force Rebase" and Abort. I tried "Force Rebase" and the next screen showed conflicts in files. The option there is "commit" which when chosen shows conflicts. Am I doing it right? Thanks

Comment: If it's up to date then your DG_child was already based on the top of origin/master. Did you fetch master from origin?

Comment: Hi Paul: I had to do "git reset –hard HEAD~1" before rebasing. Everything worked well after wards as you wrote up. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @user2654788 Don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you